# can this output be achieved from this URL using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this url

```
/home/5/test/1/user/[*]/[a,b,c/[*]/d,e/[*]/f/[1,2,3,4]/[g,h,i]]
```

The output i want is

```
/home/5/test/1/user/[*]/a
/home/5/test/1/user/[*]/b
/home/5/test/1/user/[*]/c/[*]/d
/home/5/test/1/user/[*]/c/[*]/e/[*]/f/[1,2,3,4]/g
/home/5/test/1/user/[*]/c/[*]/e/[*]/f/[1,2,3,4]/h
/home/5/test/1/user/[*]/c/[*]/e/[*]/f/[1,2,3,4]/i
```

`/home` is the key and `/5` is its value . Like this we are searching for pairs. If a pair is not found then the url breaks . So `/test` has a value `/1` and `/user` has a value `/[*]`  . The next slash has an opening bracket in which `a` is a key and it has no value as there is no slash after it so the string breaks and gives us the first output line. `b` breaks too as it as no value but `c` has a value `/[*]` so we keep that and goto the next one which is `e` and a value of `/[*]` and we add that to our string and so on till we reach the end. We are trying to keep only the good key and pair values and not the ones which breaks. Before i start thinking about how this could be done ..i was wondering if it could be done in regular expressions?  Using `\[([\S\s]*)\]` could solve my issue in finding the closing brackets but could there be a complete solution to this in regular expression? if not then how could i achieve this? Appreciate any kind of response.

Comment: To clarify: You would like a regular expression which matches strings such as `/home/5/test/1/user/999/a`, `/home/5/test/1/user/872/c/38/d`, `/home/5/test/1/user/34/c/123/e/456/f/1/g`, and so on?

Comment: yes i think you understood this.

Comment: i should be able to input a url similar to the format with different combinations but the logic of the output should be as above.

Comment: So... you want to *GENERATE* URL strings, from a regular expression???

Comment: i remember doing find and replace using regular expression. I am not quite sure what you mean by generate url

Comment: Let me try one final time... What is the input? What is the output? Your original question is a confusing jumble of words. I do not understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then the regular expression you need is:

```
/home/5/test/1/user/\d+/[abc]/\d+/[de]/\d+/f/[1-4]/[ghi]
```

Although I'm still a little confused by your question. For example, should the string: `/home/5/test/1/user/2/a/3/d` match? In my regex above it would, but I'm unclear what you want.